# Resizing notebook tabs in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How to resize notebook tabs in Tkinter? Initially, I created 4 frames inside my root, and I was able to resize using rowconfigure and columnconfigure. Now I created two tabs and shifted the 4 frames inside one of my tabs, but the problem is rowconfigure and column configure is not dynamically resizing the four frames now.

Since it was working fine with my root, I think I am having issues with tab. Will appreciate if someone can point out why this is not working and what is the solution.

Code snippet:

```py
tabControl=ttk.Notebook(master)
tab1 = Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')
tab1.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
tab1.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
tab1.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
tab1.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    
tabControl.grid()
```

Comment: Can you add an image of what you have created?

Comment: @JacksonPro I have added an image in the question (the four quadrants are different frames, and I want to resize them dynamically, which as you can see is not happening)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is `tab.columnconfigure()` and `tab.rowconfigure()`

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) 
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
  
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1') 
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2') 
tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

tab1.columnconfigure( (0,1), weight=1)
tab1.rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1)

lbl1 = Label(tab1, text='This is frame 1')
lbl2 = Label(tab1, text='This is frame 2')
lbl3 = Label(tab1, text='This is frame 3')
lbl4 = Label(tab1, text='This is frame 4')

lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0)
lbl2.grid(row=0, column=1)
lbl3.grid(row=1, column=0)
lbl4.grid(row=1, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

**Update**: using the grid to place tabControl.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) 
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
  
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1') 
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2')
tabControl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


tab1.columnconfigure( (0,1), weight=1)
tab1.rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1)

lbl1 = Label(tab1, text='This is frame 1')
lbl2 = Label(tab1, text='This is frame 2')
lbl3 = Label(tab1, text='This is frame 3')
lbl4 = Label(tab1, text='This is frame 4')

lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0)
lbl2.grid(row=0, column=1)
lbl3.grid(row=1, column=0)
lbl4.grid(row=1, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: that worked. Can you tell why it was not working with grid  package manager and worked with pack (tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")) (remaining code was same) And grid and pack doestn't work together, right?(I have used grid throughout my code) So how it is not causing any problem here?

Comment: @Shantanu you can also use gird, but it's not necessary for this case. I'll add an update.

Comment: Thanks for the update, btw what is the problem with ".grid_rowconfigure()" or ".grid_columnconfigure()" method (plz see code snippet above) (I used these methods at other places as well and they worked but was not working here) or if you can refer to some page that will be helpful.